# Do we have to add something after the switch statement

Tags: c

I am a beginner to C language.Here is the code for my C calculator but is giving me error at the switch statement saying "expected () before {" at the line where switch statement starts. The code is as follows:

```
int main()
{
    double num_1 = 0.0;
    double num_2 = 0.0;
    double n = 0.0;
    double Total = 0.0;

    printf("\nEnter 1 for add:\n ");
    printf("Enter 2 for subtract:\n ");
    printf("Enter 3 for division:\n ");
    printf("Enter 4 for multiplication:\n ");
    printf("Enter 5 for percentage:\n ");
    printf("Enter 6 for power:\n ");
    scanf("%d", & n);

    printf("Enter first number:  ");
    scanf("%d", & num_1);
    printf("Enter second number:  ");
    scanf("%d", & num_2);

    switch {
        case 1 : Total=num_1+num_2;
                 printf("The add is : %d\n",Total);
                 break;
        case 2 : Total=num_1-num_2;
                 printf("The Subtract is : %d\n",Total);
                 break;
        case 3 : Total=num_1/num_2;
                 printf("The division is : %d\n",Total);
                 break;
        case 4 : Total=num_1*num_2;
                 printf("The multiplication is : %d\n",Total);
                 break;
        case 5 : Total=num_1%num_2;
                 printf("The percentage is : %d\n",Total);
                 break;
        case 6 : Total=; pow(num_1, num_2)
                 printf("The power is : %d\n",Total);
                 break;
        default:
                printf("No Result\n");
                break;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: In case 6, you wrote ```Total=; pow(num_1, num_2)```

Comment: `pow(num_1, num_2);`

Comment: You didn't say in C what you want to "switch" on. `switch {` needs to be `switch (something) {`. It can't read your mind. :)

Comment: Surely your textbook / tutorial / other source material summarizes the syntax of a `switch` statement and gives at least one example.  The compiler helpfully points out the line of your code that it doesn't like, and even has something to say about what's wrong with it.  Compare.

Comment: @xing `n` in OP's code is of type `double`. You can't switch on `double`s in C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... is giving me error at the switch statement saying "expected () before {"

This is because the line

> ```
> switch {
> ```

must be

> ```
> switch (n) {
> ```

Some other remarks :

1) In

> ```
>  double num_1 = 0.0;
>  double num_2 = 0.0;
>  double n = 0.0;
>  double Total = 0.0;
> ```

the initializations are useless because you will (try to) reassign the variables after

The type of *n*  should be changed to an integer because of its use

2) In

> ```
> scanf("%d", & num_1);
> ....
> scanf("%d", & num_2);
> ```

`%d` means you enter an *int* but you give a pointer to a *double*, this is invalid

Replace `%d` by `%g` for instance

3) In

> ```
>  printf("The add is : %d\n",Total);
>  ...
>  printf("The Subtract is : %d\n",Total);
>  ...
>  printf("The division is : %d\n",Total);
>  ...
>  printf("The multiplication is : %d\n",Total);
>  ...
>  printf("The percentage is : %d\n",Total);
>  ...
>  printf("The power is : %d\n",Total);
> ```

the format `%d` means you print an *int* but you give a *double*, replace `%d` by `%g` for instance

4) In

> ```
> case 6 : Total=; pow(num_1, num_2)
> ```

the ',' is wrongly placed, must be

> ```
> case 6 : Total= pow(num_1, num_2);
> ```

5) you do not check if you will divide or modulo with 0

6) you do not check your *scanf* return 1 so if a valid value was entered (and not EOF too)

7) `printf("No Result\n");` can be replaced by `printf("Invalid command\n");` or `puts("Invalid command");`